# Python program doesn´t recognize pickled data, overwrites the existing file

Tags: python, function, pickle

So, I´ve been working on this little program for a college homework and I need to pickle the data, however, when I try to load the previous data and modify it, the program doesn´t modify the data that was already there, instead, it ignores it, here´s the code.

```
import pickle

diccActivos = {}

def guarda(nomArchGuardar,lista):
    try:
        f=open(nomArchGuardar,"wb")
        print("Guardando el archivo"+" "+nomArchGuardar+"...")
        pickle.dump(lista,f)
        print("El archivo",nomArchGuardar,"ha sido guardado con éxito")
        f.close()
    except:
        print("Error al grabar el archivo: ", nomArchGuardar)


def abre (nomArchLeer):
    dicc={}
    try:
        f=open(nomArchLeer,"rb")
        print("Cargando el archivo"+" "+nomArchLeer+"...")
        dicc = pickle.load(f)
        print("El archivo",nomArchLeer,"ha sido cargado con éxito")
        f.close()
    except:
        print("Error al leer el archivo: ", nomArchLeer)
    return dicc

#Definición de Funciones
def agregarActivo(diccActivos):
    ubicacion=input("Ubicación: ")
    descripcion=input("Descripción: ")
    estado=input("Estado: ")
    datosActivo=[descripcion,estado]
    diccActivos[ubicacion]=datosActivo
    guarda("activos",diccActivos)
    return diccActivos

def mostrarActivo(diccActivos,ubicacion):
    infoActivo=diccActivos[ubicacion]
    print("Ubicación: ",ubicacion)
    print("Descripción: ",infoActivo[0])
    print ("Estado: ",infoActivo[1])

def eliminarActivo(diccActivos,ubicacion):
    del(diccActivos[ubicacion])
    #Guarda el diccionario en un archivo
    guarda("activos",diccActivos)

def mostrarTodosActivos(diccActivos):
    claves = list(diccActivos.keys())
    for clave in claves:
        mostrarActivo(diccActivos,clave)
    print ("********************")

def menu():
    diccCarros=abre ("activos")
    while True:
        print("\n--------------------------------\n")
        print("1-Agregar Activo")
        print("2-Mostrar Activo")
        print("3-Eliminar Activo")
        print("4-Mostrar Todos Los Activos")
        print("5-Terminar")
        print("\n--------------------------------\n")
        opcion = int(input("Escoja una opción: "))
        if opcion == 1:
            agregarActivo(diccActivos)
        elif opcion == 2:
            ubicacion=input("Indique el código de ubicación del activo a mostrar: ")
            mostrarActivo(diccActivos,ubicacion)
        elif opcion == 3:
            ubicacion = input("Indique el código de ubicación del activo a eliminar: ")
            eliminarActivo(diccActivos,ubicacion)
        elif opcion == 4:
            mostrarTodosActivos(diccActivos)
        elif opcion == 5:
            #Guarda el diccionario en un archivo
            guarda("activos",diccActivos)
            break
        else:
            print("Opción no existente, inténtelo de nuevo")
            menu()

#Programa Principal
menu()
```

The function "mostrarActivo", for example, receives an index as a variable and should print everything that is on that index, however, if you run the program it won´t print anything because it acts as if nothing was there.

I know that the problem probably is somewhere in the "abre" function, because it loads the pickled file into the program, however, I can´t quite figure out what I´m doing wrong, this is the first time that i have worked with pickling, so I don´t have much idea of what I´m doing either.
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

In `main` you do not declare `diccCarros` as global first so the assignment declares a new variable instead of writing into your existing global variable.